# How rename the images in folder

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 35 folders and each folder contains 50 images, and every image has a different name, like `copy(3), rename, youanem` and so on. I want to rename all the images in all the folders to sequence numbers, i.e. folder `0` contains 50 images, and it should give them numbers like 0-49 and the same for the rest of the folders and their images. Folder names are 0-9 and then A-Z.

Is this possible to program for it , or i have to do it manually

This is my initial try , i didnt try it completely :

```
from os import rename, listdir

folder = "D://images//"
fnames = listdir('.')

for fname in fnames:
    if fname.startswith(folder):
        rename(fname, fname.replace(name, '', 1))
```

I am not getting idea of how to give it name

Thanks

Comment: It is possible.  What have you tried?

Comment: show us your work so we can help were you struck!!

Comment: sure let me update it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This shows how to sequence all files in a directory. For example, if the directory has 50 files, it will rename them 0-49. You can also loop through your folder names using some iterator as follows:

```
import os
for dirname in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isdir(dirname):
        for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(dirname)):
            os.rename(dirname + "/" + filename, dirname + "/" + str(i) + ".bmp")
```

Comment: Yes , i know it , but i have many folders and all folders contain many images

Comment: i also have folder's from A-Z can i also use range for it ?

Comment: @Pieter try the code I just edited in, it should work if you execute it from the directory that contains all of your folders.

Comment: Just made a change where I use `os.path.isdir` to check if it actually is a directory before traversing.

Comment: I am giving the right directory name still got the error 
`for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(dirname)):
WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid: 'best.py/*.*'`

Comment: Did you add in the `if os.path.isdir(dirname)` check? What your code is trying to do is `os.listdir()` on your python script. The check should prevent that.

Comment: `WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists`
i give the addrees manually
`dirname ="D:\Pt\FR\Char\"`

Comment: You will get that error if you try to rename your image to the directory that contains all your folders. Since your folders have numbers 0-9, if you try to rename one of your images to go to those folders, it will say "file already exists" since you are attempting to name your images 0-9 as well. Make sure to append dirname both times like I did in the last line and it should work: `os.rename(dirname + "/" + filename, dirname + "/" + str(i))`

Comment: I actually tested this script so I'm not sure why it's not working for you. I ran the script from a directory containing some folders named 0-3 with files in them that were arbitrarily named. The script was inside the same directory as all of the folders and I ran it from that directory itself.

Comment: Put the script in "D:\Pt\FR\Char\" The same directory that contains all your folders. Run the script from there with `python *.py`

Comment: The program removed the type of images like `jpg` of all images

Comment: Do all of the files have a `.jpg` type extension? if so you can just append that to your replacement string (on the second argument). I didn't know the images would have different types!

Comment: Oh that's good, I updated my code in the answer to fix that problem for you! Try it now.

Answer (score 21):

The Easiest and Cleanest, Iterate through all the files and rename with index.

```
import os
os.getcwd()
collection = "C:/darth_vader"
for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(collection)):
    os.rename("C:/darth_vader/" + filename, "C:/darth_vader/" + str(i) + ".jpg")
```

Comment: You re life saver

Answer (score 7):

You could use os.walk:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for i,f in enumerate(files):
        absname = os.path.join(root, f)
        newname = os.path.join(root, str(i))
        os.rename(absname, newname)
```

This should do exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script that I have already written for this which you are welcome to use: http://pastebin.com/gYbGEaZY.

If you just run the script it will take you through selecting the directory, defining the prefix / suffix etc. step by step and even give you the option to reverse the changes after if you are not happy with them.

Let me know if you have any questions about the code.

**EDIT**

There are a couple of parts that you may need to edit. One is a list of the file types it is looking for in get_file_extensions and the other is any paths given / environment variables referred to using os.getenv

Here is the code in case of issues with the link:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, webbrowser as wb, time, re, datetime as dt
from Tkinter import Tk
import tkFileDialog as fd
Tk().withdraw() # to stop shell opening for Tkinter
username = os.environ.get('username')
path = None
open_when_done = False
err_log = os.path.join(os.getenv('dt'),'rename_error_log.txt') # append

# Globals
g_sort_type = 'NATURAL' # options allowed for DATE or NATURAL i.e. how Windows would sort by default

def write_log_file(file_history, reverted=False):
    fname = str(username+'_'+str(dt.datetime.today())[:19]+'.csv').replace(':','-')
    logfile = os.path.join(os.environ.get('logs'), 'rename', fname.replace(' ','_'))
    f = open(logfile, 'w')
    if reverted:
        f.write('These files were reverted!!!\n')
    f.write('Filename, Old Name, New Name\n')
    for row in file_history:
        f.write(str(str(row[0])+', '+row[1]+', '+row[2]+'\n'))
    f.close()

def revert(file_history):
    for row in file_history:
        new_name = row[2]
        old_name = row[1]
        print '...reverting file', new_name, 'to', old_name
        os.rename(os.path.join(path,new_name), os.path.join(path,old_name))

def get_range(specific, file_list, excl_list):
    count = len(file_list)

    #find a zero based index range (which goes upto but not including the upper limit)
    if specific == 'Y':
        print '\n'
        print 'Please specify the name of the file you want to start from, you do not need to'
        print 'write the full name, just enough characters for the input to be unique e.g. if'
        print 'two files are called "P30687" and "P30799", a single file could be identifed by'
        print 'entering "P306".\n'
        print 'You can leave either the start filename or end filename empty.'

        c = 0
        while c <> 1:
            c, tmp = 0, None
            print '\n','Range Start:'
            print '-----------'
            first = raw_input('Please enter the file to start from: ').lower()
            if not first:
                start = 0
                break
            for name in file_list:
                if first in name.lower():
                    if not tmp:
                        tmp = name
                    c += 1
            if c == 0:
                print 'No matches were found for string:', first, ', please try again...'
            elif c > 1:
                print 'More than one file found, do you want to start from the first: '+tmp
                if raw_input('(Y/N?): ').upper() == 'Y':
                    start, c = file_list.index(tmp), 1
                else:
                    'Okay, please give a more specific name.\n'
            else:
                start = file_list.index(tmp)

        c = 0
        while c <> 1:
            c, tmp = 0, None

            print '\n','Range End:'
            print '---------'
            last = raw_input('Please enter the last file to be included: ').lower()
            if not last:
                end = count
                break
            for name in file_list:
                if last in name.lower():
                    if not tmp:
                        tmp = name
                    c += 1
            if c == 0:
                print 'No matches were found for string:', last, ', please try again...'
            elif c > 1:
                print 'More than one file found, do you want to start from the first: '+tmp+' (Y/N?):'
                if raw_input('> ').upper() == 'Y':
                    last, c = file_list.index(tmp)+1, 1
                else:
                    'Okay, please give a more specific name.\n'
            else:
                end = file_list.index(tmp)+1

    else:
        start, end = 0, count

    return start, end, count

def make_excl_list():
    finished = False
    lst = []
    print '\n'
    print 'You will now be prompted for any text strings that you want to exclude from the'
    print 'renaming process. Please notes that these are not case sensitive i.e. "mar"'
    print 'would exclude any file names containing "MAR" or "Mar" etc. \n'

    while not finished:
        lst.append(raw_input('Enter exclusion text: ').lower())
        if raw_input('Do you want to add any more? (Y/N): ').upper()[0] == 'N':
            finished = True
    return lst

def rename_files(file_list, file_type):
    happy = False
    excl_list = []

    while not happy:
        print 'No of Digits:'
        print '------------'
        print 'How many digits do you want to use for the numbering e.g. 3 for 001 - 999'
        no_of_digits = int(raw_input('> '))

        print '\n', 'Start No:'
        print '--------'
        if raw_input('Do you want to start from 1? (Y/N): ').upper() == 'Y':
            file_no = 1
        else:
            file_no = int(raw_input('Please enter the number that you want to start from: '))


        print '\n', 'Exclusions:'
        print '----------'
        print 'Do you want to specify any exclusions (i.e. files to be left unchanged) (Y/N)?'
        excl = raw_input('> ').upper()

        if excl == 'Y':
            excl_list = make_excl_list()

        print '\n', 'Range:'
        print '-----'
        print 'Do you want to specify a range of filenames to be renamed (Y/N)?'
        rnge = raw_input('> ').upper()
        start, end, count = get_range(rnge, file_list, excl_list)

        print '\n', 'Prefix:'
        print '------'
        print 'Please enter the prefix that you want to use before the numbers (can be empty)'
        prefix = raw_input('> ')

        print '\n', 'Suffix:'
        print '------'
        print 'Please enter the suffix that you want to use after the numbers (can be empty)'
        print 'For a special suffix of _ and the month the file was last modified enter _mon'
        suffix = raw_input('> ')

        l = len(str(file_no))
        eg = prefix+'0'*(no_of_digits-l)+str(file_no)+suffix+' to '+prefix+'9'*no_of_digits+suffix
        print '\n', 'Naming schema set to:', eg

        print '\n', 'Proceed?'
        print '-------'
        if raw_input('Are you happy to proceed? (Y/N): ').upper() == 'Y':
            happy = True
        else:
            if raw_input('Do you want to change directory? (Y/N): ').upper() == 'Y':
                return False
            else:
                print 'Okay, we can go through the instructions again for the current directory\n'

    file_history = [] # contains a row per file with (file_no, old_name, new_name)

    print '\n', (end - start), file_type, 'files found wuthin range.'
    if raw_input('Do you want to rename these files? (Y/N): ').upper() == 'Y':
        print '\n', 'Starting renaming process...', '\n'

        # loop through specified range within file_list
        for n in range(start,end):
            excluded = False
            if excl == 'Y':
                for ex in excl_list:
                    if ex in file_list[n].lower():
                        excluded = True
                        print '***leaving file', file_list[n], 'because of exclusion:', ex

            if not excluded:        
                if suffix == '_mon':
                    use_suffix = '_'+time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, file_list[n])))[4:7]
                else:
                    use_suffix = suffix
                l = len(str(file_no))
                ext = file_list[n][file_list[n].rfind('.'):].lower()
                new_name = prefix+'0'*(no_of_digits-l)+str(file_no)+use_suffix+ext
                file_history.append((file_no, file_list[n], new_name))
                print '...renaming file', file_list[n], 'to', new_name
                os.rename(os.path.join(path,file_list[n]), os.path.join(path,new_name))
                file_no += 1
        if open_when_done:
            print '\n', 'Opening directory...', '\n'
            wb.open(path)
    else:
        return False

    print 'The files have now been re-named. However, a record has been taken of the old'
    print 'file names so that they can be reverted if required.','\n'

    if raw_input('Are you happy with the changes? (Y/N): ').upper() == 'Y':
        write_log_file(file_history, False)
        return True
    else:
        if raw_input('Do you want to revert to the old file name? (Y/N): ').upper() == 'Y':
            revert(file_history)
            write_log_file(file_history, True)
            print '\n', 'The files should now be restored to their original names'
        return True

def sort_list(l):
    if g_sort_type.upper() == 'DATE':
        file_date_tuple_list, sorted_files = [], []

        for i in l:
            d = os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path,i))
            file_date_tuple = (i,d)
            file_date_tuple_list.append(file_date_tuple)

        file_date_tuple_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

        for i in file_date_tuple_list:
            sorted_files.append(i[0])
        return sorted_files
    else:
        convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
        alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ]
        return sorted(l, key = alphanum_key)

def get_file_extensions(file_type):
    if file_type == 'image':
        lst = [
            '.bmp',      #Bitmap Image File
            '.dds',      #DirectDraw Surface
            '.dng',      #Digital Negative Image File
            '.gif',      #Graphical Interchange Format File
            '.jpg',      #JPEG Image
            '.png',      #Portable Network Graphic
            '.psd',      #Adobe Photoshop Document
            '.pspimage', #PaintShop Pro Image
            '.tga',      #Targa Graphic
            '.thm',      #Thumbnail Image File
            '.tif',      #Tagged Image File
            '.yuv',      #YUV Encoded Image File
            '.mov',      #Movie File
            '.avi',    
            '.mp4'
            ]  
    return lst

def make_list():
    selected = False

    while not selected:
        # Date or natural sort used to order contents as Windows does
        content = sort_list(os.listdir(path))
        print '\n', 'The current directory selected is:','\n', path,'\n'

        file_type = 'image'
        ext_list = get_file_extensions(file_type)
        file_list = []
        for name in content:
            if name[name.rfind('.'):].lower() in ext_list:
                file_list.append(name)
        print ''

        if len(file_list) == 0:
            print 'No image files have been found', '\n'
        else:
            selected = rename_files(file_list, file_type)
    return path

def get_dir():
    global path
    tmp_path, pict = None, None
    computer = os.environ.get('computername')

    if computer.lower() == 'prosser-pc':
        if os.getenv('username').lower() == 'rachel.prosser':
            pict = os.path.join('E:\Users', os.getenv('username'), 'Pictures', 'Family Photos')
        else:
            pict = os.path.join('E:\Users', os.getenv('username'), 'Pictures')
    else:
        pict = os.path.join(os.environ.get('userprofile'), 'Pictures')

    # start user from relevant pictures directory...
    os.chdir(pict)

    while not path:
        # if tmp_path assigned at end of previous loop use this, otherwise prompt for dir...
        if tmp_path:
            path = tmp_path
            tmp_path = None
        else:
            print 'Please select a directory to rename images...', '\n'
            path = fd.askdirectory()

        # false is returned if something goes wrong causing the loop to continue
        path = make_list()

        if raw_input('Do you want to Continue? (Y\N): ').upper() == 'Y':
            if raw_input('Do you want to use the same directory again? (Y\N): ').upper() == 'Y':
                tmp_path = path #store to use in next loop
            path = None #this will cause the loop to continue

def main():
    print 'Program written by Chris Prosser for his beloved wife Rachel.', '\n'
    print 'This program allows the user to select a directory and rename all of the files'
    print 'of a given type within that directory.', '\n'

    try:
        get_dir()
    except NameError:
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        lines = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
        print 'An error occurred, the details shown below will be written to an error log file:'
        print err_log
        print ''.join('!! ' + line for line in lines)
        with open(err_log, "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(''.join('!! ' + line for line in lines))
    else:
        print '\n', '*** PROCESS COMPLETE ***'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: can you paste the code here?  links will rot which will make your answer useless to future readers.

Comment: @tcaswell Posted above.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is trying the glob library.

An example I had where I had to rename a bunch of images:

```
import os
import glob

current_files = glob.glob('./*.png')

for i, filename in enumerate(current_files):
    os.rename(filename, './' + '0'*(2-len(str(i))) + str(i) + '.png')
```

Where the 2 in the line above is the total length of the numbers with leadings 0's (I had 2 because I knew there was less than 100 images).

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import os.path
img_types = ['jpg', 'tif']
for dirpath, dirnames, fnames in os.walk(base_path):
    imgs = [f for f in fnames if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in img_types]
    for j, im in enumerate(imgs):
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(im)
        os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, im), os.path.join(dirpath,'{}.{}'.format(j, ext)))
```

Comment: should give the base path here : `dirpath,'{}.{}'`

Comment: `dirpath` include the basepath

Comment: this didn't give me the required result , as i have parent folder , which include 35 child folder , and that 35 child folders contain 50 images in each

Comment: what are your extensions?  If they are not 'jpg' or 'tif' this code will ignore them

Comment: I give the `base_path ="D:\Pt\FR\Char\"` and yes i change the type to bmp , but still not working

Comment: I can't help any more with out more information.  Try adding print statements to see where it is walking

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.7.x (I don't know for the previous versions) this solution works any kind of files in the directory and I have not had any errors popping up so far.

```
import os

directory = 'C:/...'
os.chdir(directory)

for i, f in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    new_name = 'asyouwant {}'.format(asyouwant, f_ext)
    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

Be careful, you must provide the extension of the file (at the end) when you define 'new_name'.

Answer (score 1):

**This Code Will Rename All The Files In That Path With Numbers Of Four digit** eg - *0001.jpg,0002.jpg,....,0999.jpg,1000.jpg*.

```
import os

os.getcwd()

path = "Images/test/"
file_type = "jpg"

for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):

    i = str(i)

    if len(i)==1:
        i = "000"+i
    elif len(i)==2:
        i = "00"+i
    elif len(i)==3:
        i = "0"+i
    else:
        i = str(i)

    os.rename(path + filename, path + str(i) + "." + file_type)
```

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2021, suppose your image file name is something "ABC_1234_5678_pre_fire.png" in folder also containing "ABC_1234_5678_post_fire.png" and you need to rename just "pre" without disturbing the order of image name. Here is a snippet which can also be tried:

```
import glob
import os
from os.path import basename, splitext

imageFile = glob.glob("/path_to_folder/*.png") # Folder containing images with name format "ABC_1234_5678_pre_fire.png" & "ABC_1234_5678_post_fire.png"

l = len(imageFile)

for i in range(l):                          
   imageName = imageFile[i]
   a, b, c, d, e = basename(imageName).split('_')

   if d == 'pre':
      d = '' # Replace with string you require
      os.rename(imageName, "/path_to_folder/" + a + "_" + b + "_" + c + "_" + d + e) # Rename the images file in the same folder at once
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i did when i had to change name of images from entire directory

```
import os
# Function to rename multiple files
def main():
   i = 0
   path="C:/Path/to/image/directory/"
   for filename in os.listdir(path):
      my_dest ="Object " + str(i) + ".jpg"
      my_source =path + filename
      my_dest =path + my_dest
  # rename() function will
  # rename all the files
      os.rename(my_source, my_dest)
      i += 1
# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
   # Calling main() function
   main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
collection = "/home/hasan/Downloads/images"
image_name = os.listdir(collection)
print("Image names are :", image_name)

for name in image_name:
    path_join = os.path.join(collection,name)
    for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(path_join)):
        os.rename("/home/hasan/Downloads/images/" + name +"/"+ filename, "/home/hasan/Downloads/images/" + name + "/" + name + "_" +str(i) + ".jpg")
```

Comment: changing name of the files/images those are in multi folder

Answer (score 0):

It's works for me

```
import os
os.getcwd()
collection = "/home/jerald/Downloads/whatsapp-images/xyz"
for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(collection)):
    os.rename("/home/jerald/Downloads/whatsapp-images/xyz/" + filename, "/home/jerald/Downloads/whatsapp-images/xyz/" + str(i) + ".jpg")
```